# Permission denied : The caller does not have permission android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

I recently installed latest versions of android studio. I tried [App Quality Insights from Firebase Crashlytics](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases?utm_source=android-studio#aqi). When I tired to open in my android studio it giving me some warning.

```
Permission denied : The caller does not have permission
```

[image]

I already tried to select the package but nothinf works.

Comment: looks like a configuration issue Have u configured firebase as the doc [suggested](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases?utm_source=android-studio#get_started) ? Also Add Studio version information with question

Comment: Yes, I have existing apps in firebase and already login in android studio

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem.

Solution: It's a configuration issue. The open Google account on Android Studio does not have access to the Firebase project. If you add Google account as user to Firebase project the problem is solved.

Comment: Or another way of looking at it, your Google account being used in Crashlytics must also be added to Android Studio.